# How to start tailing a file that has not been yet created 

Tags: shell-script, files, tail

I use `tail` to monitor the progress of jobs that I know will write their progress to disk. Almost always, I know which file they will create before they start running (the jobs are dispatched by a scheduler on a supercomputer)

Is there a way to `tail` these files before they are created? I would like to do so while avoiding [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_conditions) and/or making assumptions about how or when 
the jobs write to disk.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `-F` flag to tail (assuming you have `tail` from GNU coreutils):

```
tail -F file-that-does-not-exist
```

From `man tail`:

```
   -F     same as --follow=name --retry
   --retry
          keep trying to open a file even when it is or becomes inaccessi‐
          ble; useful when following by name, i.e., with --follow=name
   -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
          output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --fol‐
          low=descriptor are equivalent
```

Answer (score 5):

If your `tail` implementation does not have the `--retry` option, you could probably just cheat and create the file yourself:

```
$ touch file && tail-f file
```

Depending on your requirements with respect to ownership and permissions that might be sufficient.