# Tailing a New File with an Old Name

Tags: tail

This is along the lines of [How to start tailing a file that has not been yet created](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31237/how-to-start-tailing-a-file-that-has-not-been-yet-created)  with a twist: a file with the name already exists.

I have a program that is run multiple times; when the output file name is already in use, it renames the extant file by inserting `_XYZ` before the file extension where `XYZ` is the smallest integer (*e.g.,* `output.out` becomes `output_001.out`, or `output_002.out` if `output_001.out` already exists, etc.), and creates a new output file with the primary name.

If I tail the primary name, even with `-F`, it begins tailing the extant file immediately and retains the handle to that inode even when the file is renamed, ignoring the new file.

The program is run on a shared cluster with queue management, so execution begins with long & variable lags.

Is it even possible to tail the new file without waiting for it to be created first? If so, how?

Comment: Yep, same issue; I skipped it in my 'literature review' because I didn't understand the title. Now I've learned two things today.

Comment: Additionally you can skip using `tail` and accomplish something similar with `less`. See this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74279/how-do-i-less-a-filename-rather-than-an-inode-number/74283#74283. I learned how to use this one yesterday 8-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tail -F` should already do this.

Create an empty `/tmp/t/file`. Then, in terminal 1, start `tail -F`, and leave it running:

```
anthony@Zia:~$ tail -F /tmp/t/file
a
b
tail: `/tmp/t/file' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
tail: `/tmp/t/file' has appeared;  following end of new file
c
d
```

In terminal 2, I did:

```
anthony@Zia:/tmp/t$ echo a >> file
anthony@Zia:/tmp/t$ echo b >> file
anthony@Zia:/tmp/t$ mv -i file file.old; echo c >> file
anthony@Zia:/tmp/t$ echo d >> file
```

As you can see, `tail -F` does indeed follow the name, not the inode. Maybe you're using a `tail` that gives different meaning to `-F` (that flag is a BSD extension, copied later by GNU as well), or your version is buggy? You could also try `tail --follow=name --retry` (GNU tail alternate syntax) or `xtail` (which tails an entire directory).

Comment: OK, I feel like an idiot. I retested & it works as advertised; .bash_history reveals I fat-fingered the first test with `-f` instead of `-F`.

Comment: Note that the `-F` option comes from BSDs ([NetBSD first](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/tail/tail.c?rev=1.6&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup), then [FreeBSD](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.bin/tail/tail.c?revision=35081&view=markup) in 1998. GNU tail added a `--follow=name` later (textutils 1.22g 1999) and the `-F` option for compatibility with BSDs even later (textutils 2.0.15 2001).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas BSD isn't the only non-GNU tail, but thanks for the history behind it—I didn't know it, and find it interesting. And indeed, it turned out to be something else... Typo for the win :-(

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out that `-F` was not a GNUism in response to your _using a non-GNU tail_.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Indeed, you're right, I've given the wrong impression in my answer. Updated to correct. Please feel free in general to edit my answers to fix things like this.